# can't delete record in codeigniter using href

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am trying to delete particular record using href. But it's not working properly when i click on button its passing in URL like this

```
http://localhost/project_x/Organisation/Organisation/%3C?php%20echo%20base_url();?%3EOrganisation/delete_org?id=3
```

I don't know where is the mistake can anyone help me.It's passing id in URL is correctly.

Here is my controller:

```
function delete_org() {
   // Pass the $id to the org_delete() method
      $this->Org_model->org_delete($id);
      redirect('Organisation/organisation');
}
```

here is my redirect organisation function

```
public function organisation() {

    $data['organisations'] = $this->Org_model->getOrganisations();
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view("organisation", $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

Here is my model:

```
function org_delete($id) {
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('organisation');
}
```

And Here is my view buttons:

```
<?php
echo "<td class='text-center'><div class='btn-group btn-group-xs'><a href='#' data-logid='" . $org->id . "' data-target='#editGroups' data-toggle='modal' title='Edit' class='open_modal btn btn-default'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a>";
echo "<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>/Organisation/delete_org?id=$org->id'  class='btn btn-danger confirmation'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></a></div></td></tr>";                                           
?>
```

Can anyone help me where i did mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `delete_org`, where should `$id` come from? It's not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is you are adding php tag again in echo. change your delete anchor tag as below:

```
 echo "<a href='".base_url()."/Organisation/delete_org?id=$org->id'  class='btn btn-danger confirmation'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></a></div></td></tr>";
```

Also in controller define $id

```
function delete_org() {
   // Pass the $id to the org_delete() method
      $id = $_GET['id'];
      $this->Org_model->org_delete($id);
      redirect('Organisation/organisation');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this will help you :**

Change view buttons like this:

```
<?php
echo "<td class='text-center'><div class='btn-group btn-group-xs'><a href='#' data-logid='" . $org->id . "' data-target='#editGroups' data-toggle='modal' title='Edit' class='open_modal btn btn-default'><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></a>";
echo "<a href='".base_url('Organisation/delete_org?id='.$org->id)."'  class='btn btn-danger confirmation'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></a></div></td></tr>";
```

In controller :

```
function delete_org() { 
      $id = $this->input->get('id');
      $this->Org_model->org_delete($id);
      redirect('Organisation/organisation');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You may try this deleting record using codeigniter framework by data-attribute as bellow.

**html**

```
<a class="deletedata" data-id="<?php echo $data['id] ?>">delete</a>
```

**js**

```
$(".deletedata").on("click",function(){

  var id=$(this).data('id');
  var baseurl = $("#base_url").val();

  $.post(baseurl+"Products/dltProduct/"+id,function(id){
     window.location.reload();
  });
});
```

> Here my Controller name is Products. you can define your name and
>   than after define your method name.

**Controller**

```
public function dltProduct($id) {
  $this->db->where("id",$id);
  $this->db->delete("tbl_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete_org($id= NULL) {

   // Pass the $id to the org_delete() method
      $id = $this->input->post('id');
      $this->Org_model->org_delete($id);
      redirect('Organisation/organisation');
}
hope this helps you
```